# Implement 'break now' at the jint(Javascript interpreter for .NET)

Tags: jint

I'm using Jint to evaluate JavaScript within a C# application. And I'm trying to make visual debugger. While script is running at background thread, I want to control script execution at GUI(Start, Break, Step, Stop).

Jint provide control interface for debug using BreakPoint object. But I'm not sure how to implement the break funtion.

Is there any idea?